# A/B update implementation in AOSP from scratch

Tags: android, android-source, ota

I need to implement A/B seamless update on Android 11. I have AOSP source code but by default it does not support seamless update. I have read documentation regarding how to implement it but i am still struggling to understand from where to begin.

I have read related android [documentation](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/ab). It needs to have update_engine service running. But my emulator doesn't have that service. I could not find any tutorial regarding this either.

Is it possible to simulate OTA on emulator in A/B method and help me out/reference to any article with step by step process.

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

A/B update should be supported by your BSP vendor.
You can implement it by yourself, but you will need to implement a lot.

Standart Android Studio emulator do not support A/B as I know.